# Docker Registry storage not updated

Tags: docker, docker-compose, volume, mount, docker-registry

I am trying to deploy a Docker Registry with [custom storage location](https://docs.docker.com/registry/deploying/#customize-the-storage-location). The container runs well but I see no file whatsoever at the specified location. Here is my `docker-compose.yaml`:

```
version: "3"
services:
  registry:
    image: registry:2.7.1
    deploy:
      replicas: 1
      restart_policy:
        condition: always
    ports:
      - "85:5000"
    volumes:
      - "D:/Personal/Docker/Registry/data:/var/lib/registry"
```

For volumes, I have tried:

- `"data:/var/lib/registry"`
- `./data:/var/lib/registry`
- `"D:/Personal/Docker/Registry/data:/var/lib/registry"`

The yaml file and `docker-compose up` is run at `D:\Personal\Docker\Registry`. I tried to push and pull an image to the localhost:85, everything works well, so it must store the data somewhere.

Please tell me where I did wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it but for my very specific case and with a different image, so I will just post here in case someone like me needs it. This question still need answer for the official Docker image.

I have just realized the image is for Linux only and turn out I couldn't run it on Windows Server so I switched to [stefanscherer/registry-windows](https://hub.docker.com/r/stefanscherer/registry-windows/) image. I changed the `volumes` declarations to:

```
volumes:
  - ./data:c:\registry
  - ./certs:c:\certs
```

Both the storage and the certs works correctly. I am not sure how to fix it on Linux though, as I have never used Linux before.